# What would be the transition for ten coins?

Tags: transition-matrix, steady-state, finite-state-machine

- There are ten coins
- and a move is made up of flipping any three adjacent coins:
- H H T T H T H T H T  -> H T H H H T H T H T (flip: 2,3,4).
- How can this transition be represented?
- /
- EG: There are 102 coins (98H, 4T)
- Transitions are : 1) Flip over any 10 coins
- 2) if there are n heads, add (n+1 )tails. is represented as
- 1) h'=h+10−2m and t'=t−10+2m, where m=[0-10] - flipping m heads and 10-m tails
- 2) h'=h and t'= t+h+1 (add h+1 tails)
- /
- **How can I define the transition of flipping three adjacent coins?**
- Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try considering the coins in positions 1,2,4,5,7,8, and 10 (i.e. positions not divisible by 3) and find a pre-served invariant of this system.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not exactly sure on how to find the pre served invariants of the positions that are not divisible by 3

Comment: Could try asking Paul.